# sending mail in magento

Tags: magento

How to send email in magento writing an action in index controller?

my index controller;

```
public function postAction()
{           

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();     
    if(!$post) exit;
    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
    try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                echo '<div class="error-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.').'</div>';
                exit; 
            }
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
            $emailId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SAMPLE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');              
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>$storeId))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {                 
                echo '<div class="error-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later.').'</div>';
                exit;
            }               
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            echo '<div class="success-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.').'</div>';
            }   
            catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            echo '<div class="error-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later.').$e.'</div>';
            exit;
        }       
}
```

is there any wrong..
please help me to out of this..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are a few problems with the way you are calling sendTransactional().  First off, $templateId is not defined, it looks like you've actually stored the template id in $emailId.  Also, $sender, $email, and $name are undefined.  You can try something like this:

```
->sendTransactional($emailId, 'general', $post['email'], "Need a send to name here")
```

This is only going to work if you are getting a valid template id back from your call to getStoreConfig().  You'll also need to set the last name param correctly.

There could be other issues, but that's what I noticed with a quick glance anyway.

Answer (score 31):

Here's another way, if you don't need templates.
Call from a controller.

```
<?php
$body = "Hi there, here is some plaintext body content";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('John Customer');
$mail->setToEmail('customer@email.com');
$mail->setBody($body);
$mail->setSubject('The Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('yourstore@url.com');
$mail->setFromName("Your Name");
$mail->setType('text');// You can use 'html' or 'text'

try {
    $mail->send();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
    $this->_redirect('');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
    $this->_redirect('');
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this code to send a multi-part email (both html and text) without having to use a Magento email template?

Answer (score 3):

Finally i created a function for sending mail by using zend

```
public function sendMail()
    {           
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();     
        if ($post){
                $random=rand(1234,2343);

                $to_email = $this->getRequest()->getParam("email");
                $to_name = 'Hello User';
                $subject = ' Test Mail- CS';
                $Body="Test Mail Code : "; 

                $sender_email = "sender@sender.com";
                $sender_name = "sender name";

                $mail = new Zend_Mail(); //class for mail
                $mail->setBodyHtml($Body); //for sending message containing html code
                $mail->setFrom($sender_email, $sender_name);
                $mail->addTo($to_email, $to_name);
                //$mail->addCc($cc, $ccname);    //can set cc
                //$mail->addBCc($bcc, $bccname);    //can set bcc
                $mail->setSubject($subject);
                $msg  ='';
                try {
                      if($mail->send())
                      {
                         $msg = true;
                      }
                    }
                catch(Exception $ex) {
                        $msg = false;
                        //die("Error sending mail to $to,$error_msg");
                }
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($msg));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Pure curiosity, what is teh use of the variable `$random`in this method ?

Comment: 6 Years later and still no closer to the answer! 

What is the purpose of the $random variable?! Please.