# Adding unsubscribe link in custom email magento

Tags: magento

How to add unsubscribe link in custom email notification i am sending an email through zend mail function i follow this function [sending mail in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663088/sending-mail-in-magento)  in body part i want to add unsubscribe link how can we implement that?
In my e mail notification i am using this function.

```
public function sendMail()
    {           
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();     
        if ($post){
                $random=rand(1234,2343);

                $to_email = $this->getRequest()->getParam("email");
                $to_name = 'Hello User';
                $subject = ' Test Mail- CS';
                $Body="Test Mail Code : "; 

                $sender_email = "sender@sender.com";
                $sender_name = "sender name";

                $mail = new Zend_Mail(); //class for mail
                $mail->setBodyHtml($Body); //for sending message containing html code
                $mail->setFrom($sender_email, $sender_name);
                $mail->addTo($to_email, $to_name);
                //$mail->addCc($cc, $ccname);    //can set cc
                //$mail->addBCc($bcc, $bccname);    //can set bcc
                $mail->setSubject($subject);
                $msg  ='';
                try {
                      if($mail->send())
                      {
                         $msg = true;
                      }
                    }
                catch(Exception $ex) {
                        $msg = false;
                        //die("Error sending mail to $to,$error_msg");
                }
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($msg));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a custom module use this code:

```
Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email)->getUnsubscriptionLink();
```

**Explanation:**

first part is the model for the subscriber. 
If you want to see al the available methods within the model just use this code:

```
$myModel =  Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber');
foreach (get_class_methods(get_class($myModel)) as $cMethod) {
    echo '<li>' . $cMethod . '</li>';
}
```

the second part of the code `loadByEmail($email)` is to get 1 specific subscriber object. `$email` should be a string of the emailaddress.

The last part of the code is a selfexplaning method. It will generate a link to unsubscribe. This is a method that is given by Magento.

Answer (score 4):

In my Magento version I get the following code by default when creating a new newsletter template:

`Follow this link to unsubscribe <!-- This tag is for unsubscribe link  --><a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}</a>`

I expect it to work in any Magento version.

Comment: That is in the template for the newsletter, does it work outside of that?

Comment: Works great in the transactional emails on 1.6.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 1.9.
To add newsletter unsubscribe link in newsletter template here are following steps:

1. Override the core file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

by copy in local directory

> /app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

2. Open in editor to edit the code and seacrh the `function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()`
   replace the code

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

with this

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
);
```

3. and place this code in email template where you want to use unsubscribe link:

   `<a href="{{var unsubscribe}}">Unsubscribe here</a>`

That's it!

Hope this helps someone.